# Adding a new user in powershell and then giving a message after added user

Tags: powershell

How can i give an information to output that i have successfuly added a new user in an ou in powershell after the script have been run? Because, now when i am running the script i do not get any message about successful operation in powershell. I want to give a message that prints out in powershell after added the script about if the code worked or not.

```
New-ADUser -Name "Test Eksamen" -GivenName "Test" -Surname Eksamen -SamAccountName Test-UserPrincipalName Test@TestTo.local -path "OU=powershell, DC=TestTo, DC=local"
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you could save the output of that command to a variable, then use an if/else to test if that variable contains expected output for a success, something like the following:

```
$result = New-ADUser -Name "Test Eksamen" -GivenName "Test" -Surname Eksamen -SamAccountName Test-UserPrincipalName Test@TestTo.local -path "OU=powershell, DC=TestTo, DC=local"

if($result -Like "some string you expect from that command")
{
   echo "command succeeded"
}
else
{
   echo "command failed"
}
```

If the -Like command isn't giving you expected results try -Contains, here is a little blog post on the differences, I always have trouble remembering which does what haha http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/powershell-contains

Answer (score 0):

I guess Try Catch may help you.

```
Try {
    New-ADUser -Name "Test Eksamen" -GivenName "Test" -Surname "Eksamen" -SamAccountName "Test" -UserPrincipalName "Test@TestTo.local" -path "OU=powershell, DC=TestTo, DC=local"
    echo "User Created"
Catch{
    echo "User is not created"}
```

Or you could just check if user created right after "New-Aduser"

```
if (Get-aduser -filter {name -eq "Test Eksamen"}) {echo "User exists"}
else {echo "user doesn't exist"}
```